# Animar trancision entre componentes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen dia, estoy trabajando con html,css y js, estoy tratando de animar la trancision entre un componente y otro, estoy ocultando y mostrando los ids con esto:
`document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("root").style.display = "block";` y al hacer click a una funcion parecida a esto:

```js
function bienvenida() {
  document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("bienvenida").style.display ="block";
}
```

este es mi codigo para oculta los "componentes" con el id especificado, ahora mi pregunta ¿puedo hacer una animacion de transicion entre ids? que al hacer click oculte el componente con id=home muestre una animacion y luego muestre el componente con id=bienvenida.sin el uso de alguna libreria o framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo mediante animaciones **CSS**. Esa animación se la asignas a una clase y con **Javascript** añades o quitas esas clases según tus necesidades.

```js
function mostrar (color) {
  let verde = document.getElementById('verde');
  let azul = document.getElementById('azul');

  switch (color) {
    case 'verde':
      verde.classList.remove("ocultar");
      verde.classList.add("mostrar");
      azul.classList.add("ocultar");
      break;
    case 'azul':
      azul.classList.remove("ocultar");
      azul.classList.add("mostrar");
      verde.classList.add("ocultar");
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
#contenedor {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#verde {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

#azul {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mostrar {
  animation: fadein 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.ocultar {
  animation: fadeout 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to   { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="verde">

  </div>

  <div id="azul">

  </div>
  
  <button onclick="mostrar('verde')">Mostrar verde</button>
  <button onclick="mostrar('azul')">Mostrar azul</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias fue de mucha ayuda!